# Can't seem to rotate bones with IK on model?

Tags: rigging, bones, inverse-kinematics

I'm trying to curl my rigged hand models finger by rotating or changing the position of individual bones. Bone rotations or transformations are only deforming the model and the IK doesn't seem to be forcing the bones to follow along naturally with the transformations/rotations of another bone.

Is this a problem with my rigg?

EDIT: Rigged model comes from https://github.com/leapmotion/leapjs-rigged-hand/blob/master/models/Game%20Quality%20Hand/Arm:Hand/Leapmotion_Basehand_Rig_Right.fbx

[image]